# Invisible submitted code in Portable Python PyScripter Interpreter

Tags: python

I have installed Portable Python, including Portable PyScripter. When I select some code in the Editor and I submit it (with *Menu Run -> Run* or *Right-click -> Source Code -> Execute selection*), the code is well submitted in the Python Interpreter, but it is invisible. However when I directly type some code in the Interpreter, then the text is well colored. Moreover I don't find any option which could be the cause in the Editor options nor in the Interpreter options.

Since I am a little suspicious about my English, I hope my question is clearer with the screenshot below:[image: screenshot pyscripter]

I have selected the code `print("hello")` in the Editor and submitted it to the Interpreter. As you see, the code does not appear in the Interpreter but it has been well received.

Comment: What is your question? :) Are there maybe more tags that apply to your question than just 'python'?

Comment: Sorry I thought the question is clear: I want the text to be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the executed code to appear in the interpreter window you can copy the code to the clipboard and in the interpreter window right-click and select Paste & Execute.

Comment: Thanks. But there's no "Paste & Execute" in the right-click menu. I use PyScripter 2.4.1.0, is it an option available in a more recent version ? If so, is it easy to install the latest version in combination with Portable Python ?

Comment: You can get the latest version from pyscripter.googlecode.com.  You download the zip distribution and overwrite the existing files.

Comment: The folders of the zip archive don't have the same names of the folders installed with Portable Python, hence I don't see how to overwrite. Moreover when I run the file PyScripter.exe of the zip archive I get the following error message : "Python could not be properly initialized. We must quit".

Comment: Okay, I have understand, now it works fine ! Thanks !! (by the way another possibility is to install Portable Python 2.7.3.1 which includes PyScripter 2.5.3)